# apply group_conact in one column and also display all other column along with the group-concat column

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, group-concat

I have a query which looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM fw_question_options 
WHERE qdetailid in (36) 
group by graphorder ORDER BY graphorder desc
```

Now i want to `use group_concat` for only one column `id` and want to display all other column as it is 
something like:

```
SELECT group_concat(id),* FROM fw_question_options 
WHERE qdetailid in (36) 
group by graphorder ORDER BY graphorder desc
```

**But we cant do like above in mysql** and i dont want to write all the other column names in the select clause ,just want to use * and one column name for which i want to apply `group_concat`.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: thanks for the response but i want to implement using single query only.

Answer (score 0):

Write other column after `*` then query will works. My suggestion is that do not use `*` in your query.

Try this:

```
SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(id) 
FROM fw_question_options 
WHERE qdetailid IN (36) 
GROUP BY graphorder 
ORDER BY graphorder DESC
```

Comment: above query is not giving the expected output

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
SELECT group_concat(id),fw.* FROM fw_question_options as fw 
WHERE qdetailid in (36) 
group by graphorder ORDER BY graphorder desc
```

Comment: this will give  me 2 times id which i dont want

Comment: yes, because you don't want column specification in the select statement. If you are using * in the selection it gives all columns of table

Comment: ya thats the problem i want group_concat row and all the other row except the group concat one